# How to record mobile application using jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, performance-testing, mobile, mobile-applications

I need to do load testing of my mobile application. I am using android mobile.
while i am trying to record the script using Jmeter nothing is getting recorded.
I had followed this process to record:
I had installed the rootCA certificate on my mobile
I had given proxy same as in the jmeter and ip address with respect to my system ip
My mobile and laptop are under same wifi network

Although I am unable to record when I checked in log viewer "Ensure browser is set to accept the jmeter proxy cert: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown" this is the error message I got. And in mobile I am getting "session expired ! try again" message ...
I even modified the source code.

Plz help me guys

Answer (score 1):

What operating system does your "mobile" run?

- For iOS you need to turn on ["ENABLE FULL TRUST FOR ROOT CERTIFICATES" toggle](https://support.apple.com/en-nz/HT204477) under `Settings -> General -> About -> Certificate Trust Settings`

  [image]
- For [Android](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000285357-Recording-Using-Android-Devices-Recording-Using-Android-Devices) you need to add the next section to your [network_security_config.xml file](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config):

  ```
   <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
       <trust-anchors>
           <certificates src="system" />
           <certificates src="user" />
       </trust-anchors> 
   </base-config>
  ```

  In case if you don't have access to application source code you will need to [root your Android device](https://www.xda-developers.com/root/)

---

- If you have another mobile operating system - refer to its documentation.

Comment: I had tried by making source code changes but still facing the same issue...